# Can I force to display the file in browser rather than download it for a particular sub url?

Tags: django, http-headers

Can I do this through javascript or modifying the HTTP header?

```
http://www.example.com/downloads/*
```

Any files coming out of this should not be auto-download, instead, display on browser. Can I overwrite the rules set by the browser? Can I also set this limit to just this particular sub url?

Thank you.

Thanks.

Comment: @Tim. Thanks. What kind of code do you need to see?

Comment: Well, maybe more information about your server or configuration files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of file are you working with?

This is used through the HTTP header.  If the mime type is a certain type, the browser will decide whether to download or display it.  You can also force downloading.  The file type will help.

For text files, set the content-type to `text/plain`. For JPEGs, set it to `image/jpeg`, and for PNGs set it to `image/png`.  This should overwrite any `attachment` values Django is setting.

Comment: I want to be make it not auto-downloadable for a particular sub url. I should've edited my question more specifically. Just in a moment. I don't want it to download. Even a simple txt right now is set to auto-download. Commonly, we want to be able to see image and text file on the browser :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the Content-Disposition header for this. It should any haggling over content-type.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt

Answer (score 0):

The default document type is declared under your server settings, not in how you ***link*** to the file. If you are under Apache try looking in httpd.conf for

```
DefaultType text/plain
```

If it says something different that may be your problem. `text/plain` should set all unknowns to download and be viewed in the browser as text.

**EDIT:**

I don't know any way of modifying this behavior through javascript as it has to be in the header of the file being downloaded.